# Concatenar id pela descrição em um array no javascript

Tags: javascript, array, concatenação-de-string

Eu tenho um array em js com somente um id e uma descrição, exemplo:

```
var variavel = [{id: 1, descrição: 'Brasil'},
             {id: 2, descrição: 'Brasil'},
             {id: 3, descrição: 'Chile'},
             {id: 4, descrição: 'Chile'},
             {id: 5, descrição: 'Chile'},
             {id: 6, descrição: 'Argentina'}];
```

Porém eu gostaria de concatenar os id e deixar somente a descrição, basicamente dessa forma:

```
var variavel = [{id: '1,2', descrição: 'Brasil'},
                     {id: '3,4,5', descrição: 'Chile'},
                     {id: '6', descrição: 'Argentina'}];
```

Como posso fazer isso? Um `loop/for` resolveria?

**OBS: Não utilizo/posso usar Jquery nesse projeto**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem diversas formas de fazer isso. Recomendo usar o método do Javascript `forEach` para iterar sobre seu array, e compor um novo array. Ficaria algo assim:

```js
// Array com os valores indicados no enunciado.
var array = [
    {id: '1', descricao: 'Brasil'},
    {id: '2', descricao: 'Brasil'},
    {id: '3', descricao: 'Chile'},
    {id: '4', descricao: 'Chile'},
    {id: '5', descricao: 'Chile'},
    {id: '6', descricao: 'Argentina'}
];

// Novo Array que será populado de acordo com a lógica apresentada.
var novoArray = [];

// Aqui usamos o método do Javascript, forEach, presente nos arrays para percorrer os objetos
array.forEach(function(item){
    // Aqui vamos verificar através do método map, se a descrição já foi salva dentro do novoArray.
    var indice = novoArray.map(function(e) { 
        return e.descricao; 
    }).indexOf(item.descricao);

    // Se achamos, vamos nesse índice localizado, e concatenamos o ID ao já existente
    // Se não, usamos o método push, para atribuir o novo item ao novoArray.
    if(indice >= 0) {
        novoArray[indice].id += ', ' + item.id;
    } else {
        novoArray.push(item);
    }
});

console.log(novoArray);
```

Ao final a variável `novoArray` terá o seguinte valor como solicitado:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1, 2",
    "descricao": "Brasil"
  },
  {
    "id": "3, 4, 5",
    "descricao": "Chile"
  },
  {
    "id": "6",
    "descricao": "Argentina"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Dois loops resolvem. O primeiro percorre a variavel com os campos repetidos, dentro faz um novo loop para verificar se aquele objeto já existe na nova variável, se existir, atualiza o id, se não, adiciona

```js
const variavel = [
  {id: 1, descrição: 'Brasil'},
  {id: 2, descrição: 'Brasil'},
  {id: 3, descrição: 'Chile'},
  {id: 4, descrição: 'Chile'},
  {id: 5, descrição: 'Chile'},
  {id: 6, descrição: 'Argentina'}
];

const novaVariavel = [];

for (const objeto of variavel) {
  let existe = false;

  for (let i = 0; i < novaVariavel.length; i++) {
    if (objeto['descrição'] === novaVariavel[i]['descrição']) {
      novaVariavel[i].id += `,${objeto.id}`;
      existe = true;
    }
  }

  if (!existe) {
    novaVariavel.push(objeto);
  }
}

console.log(novaVariavel)
```

Answer (score 2):

Vou fazer minha colaboração com um algoritmo O(n) ao invés de O(n^2), usando dois laços de repetição não-aninhados.

---

O primeiro laço agrupa os `id` por país:

```
var grupos = {};
lista.forEach(function(obj) {
    grupos[obj.descricao] = grupos[obj.descricao] || [];
    grupos[obj.descricao].push(obj.id)
});
```

O conteúdo de `grupo` agora é:

```
{
    "Brasil": [1, 2],
    "Chile": [3, 4, 5],
    "Argentina": [6]
}
```

---

No segundo loop apenas percorro o objeto anterior e populo o array com os dados desejados:

```
Object.keys(grupos).forEach(function(pais) {
    resultado.push({
        id: grupos[pais].join(','),
        descricao: pais
    });
});
```

Resultado:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1,2",
        "descricao": "Brasil"
    },
    {
        "id": "3,4,5",
        "descricao": "Chile"
    },
    {
        "id": "6",
        "descricao": "Argentina"
    }
]
```

---

Código funcionando:

```js
let lista = [
  {id: 1, descricao: 'Brasil'},
  {id: 2, descricao: 'Brasil'},
  {id: 3, descricao: 'Chile'},
  {id: 4, descricao: 'Chile'},
  {id: 5, descricao: 'Chile'},
  {id: 6, descricao: 'Argentina'}
];
 
let grupos = {};

lista.forEach(obj => {
  grupos[obj.descricao] = grupos[obj.descricao] || [];
  grupos[obj.descricao].push(obj.id)
});

let resultado = [];

Object.keys(grupos).forEach(pais => {
  resultado.push({
    id: grupos[pais].join(','),
    descricao: pais
  })
});

console.log(resultado)
```

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que você precise de algo nesse sentido (rodando):

```
var groups = {};
for (var i = 0; i < variavel.length; i++) {
    var groupName = variavel[i].descrição;
    if (!groups[groupName]) {
        groups[groupName] = [];
    }
    groups[groupName].push(variavel[i].id);
}
    variavel = [];
    for (var groupName in groups) {
    variavel.push({descrição: groupName, id: groups[groupName]});
}
```

Espero ter ajudado.
Abraços,

Answer (score 1):

Dentre tantas respostas, segue mais uma opção:

```js
var lista = [{id: 1, descrição: 'Brasil'},
             {id: 2, descrição: 'Brasil'},
             {id: 3, descrição: 'Chile'},
             {id: 4, descrição: 'Chile'},
             {id: 5, descrição: 'Chile'},
             {id: 6, descrição: 'Argentina'}];

    var result = [...lista.reduce((item, {id,descrição}) => {
      if (!item.has(descrição)) 
        item.set(descrição, {id,descrição});
      
      item.get(descrição).id = item.get(descrição).id == id ? String(id) : item.get(descrição).id + ',' + id;
      return item;
    }, new Map()).values()];

    console.log(result);
```